# Quick sort in C why an extra swap?

Tags: c, quicksort

I am trying to understand Quick sort algorithm and implement it in C language. I found this code in programiz;

```
// Quick sort in C

#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}
int partition(int array[], int low, int high) {
  
  
  int pivot = array[high];
  int i = (low - 1);

  for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= pivot) {
      i++;
      swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }
  }

// please note Here!!!!!

  swap(&array[i + 1], &array[high]);
  return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) {
  if (low < high) {
    
    
    int pi = partition(array, low, high);
    
    quickSort(array, low, pi - 1);
    
    quickSort(array, pi + 1, high);
  }
}
void printArray(int array[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%d  ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int main() {
  int data[] = {8, 7, 2, 1, 0, 9, 6};
  int n = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
  quickSort(data, 0, n - 1);
  printf("Sorted array in ascending order: \n");
  printArray(data, n);
}
```

This code is working. But I can't understand why they iterate upto `<high` in `partition` function and do the final swap in another step. Instead why don't they just go like this;

```
int partition(int array[], int low, int high) {
  int pivot = array[high];
  int i = (low - 1);

  for (int j = low; j <=  high; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= pivot) {
      i++;
      swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }
  }
 return (i);
}
```

I checked geeksforgeeks also. They also have the same code. That's why I ask this. Please help me

https://www.programiz.com/dsa/quick-sort

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/amp/

Comment: Micro-optimization: you can skip the comparison, since you know that `array[high] == pivot`.